# Aggregate multiple rows with multiple columns into one row with the same columns and concatenated data in R

Tags: r, aggregate, rows

I have pre-calculated some mean and standard deviation data to create a two-row data frame. How can I aggregate that data into one row with the same columns, concatenating the data into strings, all following the same format?

Here is my data

| funct | t1 | t2 | t3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mean | 52 | 99 | 35 |
| sd | 6 | 18 | 2 |

This is the result I want:

| funct | t1 | t2 | t3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mean(sd) | 52(6) | 99(18) | 35(2) |

I've looked at *aggregate* and *apply* but not sure how to effect this.

Here is the code to generate the above:

```
df <- data.frame(funct=c("Mean","sd"),
                 t1=c(52,6),
                 t2=c(99,18),
                 t3=c(35,2))

result <- data.frame(funct="Mean(sd)",
                     t1="52(6)",
                     t2="99(18)",
                     t3="35(2)")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
t(apply(df, 2, function(x) paste(x[1], '(',x[2],')', sep = ''))) %>% as.data.frame
     funct     t1     t2     t3
1 Mean(sd) 52( 6) 99(18) 35( 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sprintf`

```
data.frame(setNames(as.list(sprintf('%s(%s)', df[1,], df[2,])), names(df)))
```

-output

```
  funct    t1     t2    t3
1 Mean(sd) 52(6) 99(18) 35(2)
```